Android Keyboard language setting crashes on Redmi phones
I have created a custom Android keyboard, with code from the AOSP - a few versions back.
It works fine on most devices but crashes when asking the user to choose a default language
  intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS);
  intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);

If I create the intent like that, then it crashes on Redmi phones with an error message.

`Process: com.android.settings, PID: 3082
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to call observer method
at androidx.lifecycle.ClassesInfoCache$MethodReference.invokeCallback(ClassesInfoCache.java:226)
at androidx.lifecycle.ClassesInfoCache$CallbackInfo.invokeMethodsForEvent(ClassesInfoCache.java:194)
at androidx.lifecycle.ClassesInfoCache$CallbackInfo.invokeCallbacks(ClassesInfoCache.java:186)
at androidx.lifecycle.ReflectiveGenericLifecycleObserver.onStateChanged(ReflectiveGenericLifecycleObserver.java:37)
at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:354)
at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.forwardPass(LifecycleRegistry.java:265)
at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.sync(LifecycleRegistry.java:307)
at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.moveToState(LifecycleRegistry.java:148)
at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:134)
at com.android.settingslib.core.lifecycle.ObservablePreferenceFragment.onStart(ObservablePreferenceFragment.java:98)
at com.android.settings.core.InstrumentedPreferenceFragment.onStart(InstrumentedPreferenceFragment.java:73)
at com.android.settings.SettingsPreferenceFragment.onStart(SettingsPreferenceFragment.java:1100)
at com.android.settings.dashboard.DashboardFragment.onStart(DashboardFragment.java:219)
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:3019)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.start(FragmentStateManager.java:568)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:277)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:113)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1331)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2772)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStart(FragmentManager.java:2722)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchStart(FragmentController.java:273)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:486)
at com.android.settingslib.core.lifecycle.ObservableActivity.onStart(ObservableActivity.java:74)
at com.android.settings.SettingsActivity.onStart(SettingsActivity.java:578)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1544)
at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:8548)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3850)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2389)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8261)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:559)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:954)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.settingslib.inputmethod.InputMethodSubtypePreference cannot be cast to com.android.settingslib.PrimarySwitchPreference
at com.android.settingslib.inputmethod.InputMethodAndSubtypeUtilCompat.saveInputMethodSubtypeListForUserInternal(InputMethodAndSubtypeUtilCompat.java:249)
at com.android.settingslib.inputmethod.InputMethodAndSubtypeUtilCompat.saveInputMethodSubtypeList(InputMethodAndSubtypeUtilCompat.java:174)
2024-04-20 18:20:08.742  3082-3082  AndroidRuntime          com.android.settings                 E      at com.android.settingslib.inputmethod.InputMethodAndSubtypeEnablerManagerCompat.setAutoSelectionSubtypesEnabled(InputMethodAndSubtypeEnablerManagerCompat.java:227)
at com.android.settingslib.inputmethod.InputMethodAndSubtypeEnablerManagerCompat.updateAutoSelectionPreferences(InputMethodAndSubtypeEnablerManagerCompat.java:276)
at com.android.settingslib.inputmethod.InputMethodAndSubtypeEnablerManagerCompat.refresh(InputMethodAndSubtypeEnablerManagerCompat.java:88)
at com.android.settings.inputmethod.InputMethodAndSubtypePreferenceController.onStart(InputMethodAndSubtypePreferenceController.java:60)
at com.android.settingslib.core.lifecycle.Lifecycle.onStart(Lifecycle.java:124)
at com.android.settingslib.core.lifecycle.Lifecycle.-$$Nest$monStart(Unknown Source:0)
at com.android.settingslib.core.lifecycle.Lifecycle$LifecycleProxy.onLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.java:222)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at androidx.lifecycle.ClassesInfoCache$MethodReference.invokeCallback(ClassesInfoCache.java:222)
... 38 more`
The important part there, being that it's a Class Cast Exception in a class that I can't do anything about
But it gets worse.
On some phones this code crashes the app
 intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS);
 intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);

On other phones this code crashes the app
 intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_LOCALE_SETTINGS);
 intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);

However, the Google Gboard keyboard works fine.
What can i do ?
